# Oreintation Stop in Android

Tags: android, css

I am developing a Site which is responsive for all devices.I want to run that site only with landscape mode not with portrait mode...How can I do that help me out with Code or some references

Thanks in Advance

Comment: are you developing android app or a website?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do this through the viewport. Here is an example of JavaScript that could help you.

```
var viewportm = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
if (viewportm) {
    viewportm.content = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0';
    document.body.addEventListener('gesturestart', function () {
        viewportm.content = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.25, maximum-scale=1.6';
    }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For running main activity in Portrate or Landscape mode select proper parameter.
Here is an example for C# android (mono):

```
[Activity(Label = "TestAct", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon",ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
```

Javad

Comment: He is not developing an application for Android, he's trying to disable portrait mode on his website on Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` set the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".YourAppClass"
               android:label="@string/app_name"
               android:screenOrientation="landscape"  
               >
```

Comment: Read his question, he is not asking how to do this in an application, he wants to lock the landscape screen orientation for his website.